# Как разрешить зависимость в композере

Tags: composer

Есть оригинальное расширение `wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform`. Ссылка на [composer.json](https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform/blob/master/composer.json).
Есть форк в котором исправлен некоторый баг `spiro-stathakis/yii2-dynamicform`. Ссылка на [composer.json](https://github.com/spiro-stathakis/yii2-dynamicform/blob/master/composer.json)

В моём проекте есть расшерние у которого в зависимостях указано "wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform": "dev-master"

В `composer.json` проекта я подключаю `spiro-stathakis/yii2-dynamicform` и указываю ссылку на репозиторий. В итоге у меня скачиваются оба раширения(оригинальное и форкнутое), но в проекте используется оригинальная версия.

Как сделать так, что бы использовался форк?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно а своем проекте использовать форк-версию какого-то оригинального пакета (это может быть ваш или чужой форк), то вам нужно:

1. Добавить VCS репозиторий c форком пакета:

```
composer config repositories.yii2-dynamicform vcs spiro-stathakis/yii2-dynamicform
```

2. Установить пакет (с оригинальным названием!) `wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform`:

```
composer require wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform dev-master
```

3. Profit!

PS: *dev-master* - название ветки репозитория, в данном случае это *master*

---

Для вашего конкретного случая вам нужно:

1. Удалить установленные пакеты `wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform` и `spiro-stathakis/yii2-dynamicform`
2. Вернуть оригинальное название для пакета в [composer.json](https://github.com/spiro-stathakis/yii2-dynamicform/blob/master/composer.json)
3. Установить пакет `wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform`:

```
composer require wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform dev-master
```

4. Profit!

PS: *dev-master* - название ветки репозитория, в данном случае это *master*

Comment: Получается, всё упирается в `name` в `composer.json` ? 
Проблема в том что это не мой форк. В принципе я решил проблему таким же образом - форкнул проект себе и изменил `name` на оргининальное. Но тут у меня возникает еще один вопрос: получается это `bad-practice` форкатся от чужого проекта и менять имя вендора?
Или всё таки есть какое то решение без изменения `name` ? Что то типа, "Товарищ композер, если будут просить `vendor/package`, ты туда не ходи, ты суда ходи и скачивай `another-vendor/package`

Comment: Если название вендора или пакета изменено, то это уже другой пакет со всеми вытекающими. На второй Ваш вопрос я ответил в своем ответе - любой пакет (vendor/name) можно заменить одноименным пакетом из локального репозитория. Если заданы локальные репозитории, то поиск для установки запрошенных пакетов composer делает вначале в них, а в случае неудачи - поиск продолжается в глобальных репозиториях по-умолчанию.